# Does adding a forward hook to a layer of ensure that the gradient of the loss calculated using the layer's output will be calculated automatically?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a model

```
class NewModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,output_layer,*args):
        self.output_layer = output_layer
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.output_layer = output_layer
        self.selected_out = None
        #PRETRAINED MODEL
        self.pretrained = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
    
        #TAKING OUTPUT FROM AN INTERMEDIATE LAYER

        #self._layers = []
        for l in list(self.pretrained._modules.keys()):
            #self._layers.append(l)
            if l == self.output_layer:
                handle = getattr(self.pretrained,l).register_forward_hook(self.hook)
   
    def hook(self,module, input,output):
        self.selected_out = output

    def forward(self, x):
        return x = self.pretrained(x)
```

I have two target outputs, one which is same as any label of an image and the second one is the same dimensions as the output obtained from `self.output_layer`, called `target_feature`

```
out = model(img)
layerout = model.selected_out
```

Now, if I want to calculate the loss of layerout with the target feature map, can it be done like the line written below?

```
loss = criterion(y_true, out) + feature_criterion(layerout, target_feature)
```

Or do I need to add `backward_hooks`?

In this Kaggle notebook

https://www.kaggle.com/sironghuang/understanding-pytorch-hooks

it is written that `loss.backward()` cannot be used when using `backward_hooks`.

Quoting the author

```
# backprop once to get the backward hook results
out.backward(torch.tensor([1,1],dtype=torch.float),retain_graph=True)
#! loss.backward(retain_graph=True)  # doesn't work with backward hooks, 
#! since it's not a network layer but an aggregated result from the outputs of last layer vs target
```

Then how can be gradient be calculated based on the loss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get two outputs from your model, calculate two losses, then combine them and backpropagate. I imagine you come from Tensorflow & Keras from the way you tried implementing it. In Pytorch, it's actually fairly straight foward, you can do this very easily because of its purely *functional* aspect.

This is just an example:

```
class NewModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_layer, *args):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.pretrained = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
        self.output_layer = output_layer
        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.pretrained(x)
        features = self.output_layer(out)
        return out, features
```

On inference, you will get two results per call:

```
>>> m = NewModel(nn.Linear(1000, 10))
>>> x = torch.rand(16, 3, 224, 224)
>>> y_pred, y_feature = m(x)
```

Call you loss functions:

```
>>> loss = criterion(y_pred, y_true) + feature_criterion(y_feature, target_feature)
```

Then, backpropagate with `loss.backward()`.

So no need for hooks, nor complicated gradient on your `.backward` call!

---

*Edit* - If you wish to extract an intermediate layer output, keep the hook, that's good. And just modify the `forward` definition.

```
def forward(self, x):
    out = self.pretrained(x)
    return out, self.selected_out
```

For example:

```
>>> m = NewModel(output_layer='layer1')
>>> x = torch.rand(16, 3, 224, 224)
>>> y_pred, y_feature = m(x)

>>> y_pred.shape, y_feature.shape
(torch.Size([16, 1000]), torch.Size([16, 64, 56, 56]))
```

Also, what I said above about the loss stills stands. Compute your loss, then call `loss.backward()`.

Comment: self.output_layer is actually the name of the intermediate layer whose output I am using in the second loss. Suppose, 'layer4' is the name of a layer in ResNet. So, I set self.output_layer = 'layer4' and then I used forward_hooks to get the output from this layer and then I went on to calculate the loss with this output.

Comment: Sorry about that, should have payed more attention. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I used this loss function just for testing 

`loss = torch.sum((label-out)**2) + torch.sum((layerout-x2))`

But I get error 

`RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`

.................

`label = torch.Tensor(np.array([1]+[0]*999)).to('cuda:0')` and `x2 = torch.Tensor(np.random.random((2048,7,7)).to('cuda:0')`

Comment: I added `self.selected_out.requires_grad = True` inside the `hook` method. But that means that it will be executed every time the `hook` method is called.

Comment: Which layer are you passing as `output_layer`? I've tried with `output_layer=layer4` to get an layer output shape of `(-1, 512, 7, 7)` and it works fine. You shouldn't have to require any gradients. There must be something you haven't mentioned that you are doing in your code.

Comment: Yeah! I am sorry, I made a mistake. I set the requires_grad of the parameters in the layer to False. That's why the error was occurring. No error if requires_grad of the parameters in the layer from the output is being taken is set to True. Thank you!!